# Get params inside custom validator in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, mongoose

In my `express` + `mongo` application, I am using `mongoose` for database schema.

For the schema, I need a custom validator say "for checking whether length is x"

Below is my schema containing that custom validator

```
var schema = new Schema({
    ...,
    contactNumber: {
        type: Number,
        validate: [
            {
                validator: hasLength,
                message: "Contact number must be 10 digits",
                length: 10
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

And below is the custom validator function:

```
function hasLength(str, length) {
    let pattern = "^d{" + length + "}$";
    let regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

    return regex.test(str);
}
```

In this validator function, I want to access the `length` parameter from the above schema.

I know this function code will not work properly. So I need help from someone that how can I access that length variable in my validator function.

Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    ...,
    contactNumber: {
        type: Number,
        validate: [
            {
                validator: hasLength(10),
                message: "Contact number must be 10 digits",
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}

const hasLength = length => str => {
   let pattern = "^d{" + length + "}$";
   let regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

   return regex.test(str);
}
```

Comment: you could (should?) just use the [built-in](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) validators for this, however.

Comment: mongoose doesn't have such a built-in validator and also i want to study how to create such a custom validator. I will try your code and let you know the result.

Comment: @SherinJose You’re incorrect, they have min and max for number schemas and have minLength and maxLength validators for string schemas.

Comment: min and max for numbers are not for counting digits, it is the maximum number and minimum number.

Comment: I have checked your code and it is working fine for me. thank you @Adam

Comment: @SherinJose use two validators: min:1000 and max:9999 will restrict you to a 4 digit number pretty easily.

Comment: I want to validate a 16 digit number , so if i use min and max for that, i think it is not the right way